# Canciones perdidas

Tags: letras-de-canciones

Mi abuela solía cantar (muy mal) un par de canciones infantiles que yo quisiera rescatar...

Ella nació en Barcelona en 1911 y hablaba tanto español como catalán. Lo poco que recuerdo de ambas canciones es

- “Patito, patito, color de café. Si tu no me quieres, yo ya sé porqué...”
- “ Ay, ay, ay, Don José. Cómo madruga usted.”  “ Madrugo porque tengo la vaca en el corral, y el  vecino de enfrente me la quiere robar...”

¿Son conocidas? ¿Folclóricas? Agradeceré cualquier información, aunque solo sea parcial.

Comment: He aquí una grabación de patito patito: https://youtu.be/xnzQvGco0fA

Comment: ¡Absolutamente fantástica! Gracias

Comment: Con gusto, contento porque le sirve. Saludos! (Quizás puedas encontrar la otra también en Youtube.)